# ng build --prod not working in Azure CICD pipelines

Tags: angular, azure-devops

I'm setting up my application CI/CD in Azure but I couldn't figure out why it still failed in build process.

this is my yaml

```html
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '8.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: |
    npm uninstall -g angular-cli
    npm cache clean or npm cache verify #(if npm > 5)
    npm install -g @angular/cli@7.1.4
  displayName: 'npm install @angular/cli'

- script: |
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm build'
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '/src/app/dist/my-app'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

I thought it was the CLI but after I followed the solutions on the internet still if fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

azure CI/CD doesn't have `ng` utility installed. But it knows about `npm`. Just add npm script in package.json to call `ng build --prod` in it and then call it though npm from yaml.

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
  "build:prod": "ng build --prod"
}
....
// yaml
- script: |
  npm run build:prod
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply install angular/cli without modifying package.json

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli@^9
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Comment: does that really work for you ? it's what I've been trying to make work for days

Comment: @FrancisDucharme sorry the late response, if I posted means that at that time sure it worked then, don't know now also because I left Azure cloud. Good Luck!